# Ruby: Active admin retrieve value from saved filter in session

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session, activeadmin

I used this code in the link below to get active admin filters saved in a session:
https://gist.github.com/tinynumbers/5896537

It's been very helpful, although now I need to use these saved filters on my edit and new pages. I got the session and found that I could do it with this:

```
session[:last_search_filter].to_a[1][1]["saved_filter"]
```

Is this really the only good way to do this? Is there any other better way to do this that doesn't require working with array indexes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh, I could figure it out actually. It happened to be very simple, I just needed to get the session's hash names to get the correct values.

```
session[:last_search_filter][:"action-index-controller-admin_interactions"]["saved_filter"]
```